# Why my heaps do not get cleared after they are deleted?

Tags: c++

I am making a program that requires a heap containing a pointer to other heaps containing frame data. but I noticed that while I clean the heaps after they are no longer needed, they still remain busy. also attached an image of memory consumption.

Here's an image of RAM usage going up.

[image]
MB after 10 min.

[image]
GB after 30 min.

After which there was a crash due to a memory access error.

```cpp
    void Trap(vlByte **lpImageData, vlUInt uiCount)
    {
        if (lpImageData != 0)
        {
            for (vlUInt i = 0; i < uiCount; i++)
            {
                if (lpImageData[i] != 0)
                {
                    delete[]lpImageData[i];
                }
            }
            delete[]lpImageData;
        }
    }
```

cleanup function, called upon failure and completion.

the code itself

```cpp
    vlByte** lpImageDataRGBA8888 = 0;

    lpImageDataRGBA8888 = new vlByte*[uiCount];
    memset(lpImageDataRGBA8888, 0, uiCount * sizeof(vlByte *));

    vlUInt uiImageSize = vlImageComputeImageSize(uiWidth, uiHeight, 1, 1, IMAGE_FORMAT_RGBA8888);
    for (vlUInt i = 0; i < uiCount; i++)
    {
        lpImageDataRGBA8888[i] = new vlByte[uiImageSize];

        if (!vlImageConvertToRGBA8888(vlImageGetData(iType == 1 ? i : 0, iType == 2 ? i : 0, iType == 3 ? i : 0, 0), lpImageDataRGBA8888[i], uiWidth, uiHeight, vlImageGetFormat()))
        {
            Print("Unable to convert %i frame/face/slice\n", 1 + i);
            Trap(lpImageDataRGBA8888, uiCount);
            return;
        }
    }

    ...

    if (!vlImageCreateMultiple(uiWidth, uiHeight, uiFrames, uiFaces, uiSlices, lpImageDataRGBA8888, &CreateOptions))
    {
        Print("Error Creation Multiple Image\n");
        Trap(lpImageDataRGBA8888, uiCount);
        return;
    }

    Trap(lpImageDataRGBA8888, uiCount);
```

Minimal reproducible.

```cpp
    #include <iostream>

    void DLLvlImageCreateMultiple(unsigned int uiCount, unsigned char** lpImageDataRGBA8888)// The dll code
    {
        unsigned char** lpNewImageDataRGBA8888 = 0;

        unsigned int uiImageSize = 256 * 256 * 4; // width * height * byte per pixel

        lpNewImageDataRGBA8888 = new unsigned char* [uiCount];
        memset(lpNewImageDataRGBA8888, 0, uiCount * sizeof(unsigned char*));

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < uiCount; i++)
        {
            lpNewImageDataRGBA8888[i] = new unsigned char[uiImageSize];
        }

        lpImageDataRGBA8888 = lpNewImageDataRGBA8888;
    }

    void trap(unsigned char** lpImageData, unsigned int uiCount)
    {
        if (lpImageData != 0)
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < uiCount; i++)
            {
                if (lpImageData[i] != 0)
                {
                    delete[]lpImageData[i];
                }
            }
            delete[]lpImageData;
        }
    }


    void process()
    {
        unsigned char** lpImageDataRGBA8888 = 0;
        unsigned int uiCount = 1; // frames
        unsigned int uiImageSize = 1024 * 1024 * 4; // width * height * byte per pixel

        lpImageDataRGBA8888 = new unsigned char* [uiCount];
        memset(lpImageDataRGBA8888, 0, uiCount * sizeof(unsigned char*));
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < uiCount; i++)
        {
            lpImageDataRGBA8888[i] = new unsigned char[uiImageSize];
        }

        DLLvlImageCreateMultiple(uiCount, lpImageDataRGBA8888);

        trap(lpImageDataRGBA8888, uiCount);
    }

    int main()
    {
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 10240; i++) {
            std::cout << i << "\n";
            process();
        }

        std::cin;
    }
```

Comment: This has been asked here before. The OS is not required to reclaim memory as soon as it is deallocated by a program. Let me try to find a duplicate.

Comment: Yes. quite possibly, but I'm not sure. that no chisi should occur for 26 minutes. and the program occupy 1.8 GB

Comment: and in the end, get an access error due to overflow.

Comment: That is different than what I imagined. It does look like a memory leak. You'll have to post a [mcve] to let others have a shot at diagnosing where the problem could be.

Comment: Why are you using antiquated C-style arrays?

Comment: Well. I found trouble.

Comment: This need for dll.

Comment: C and C++ aren't anywhere required to return freed memory to the operating system at all.

Comment: Where is `DLLvlImageCreateMultiple` memory freed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything allocated in `DLLvlImageCreateMultiple` is a memory leak. That explains why memory usage keeps going up monotonically.

The line

```
lpImageDataRGBA8888 = lpNewImageDataRGBA8888;
```

does not change the value of the variable in the calling function. It just changes the value of the function local variable.

You'll have to:

1. Return the memory allocated as the return value of the function

   ```
   unsigned char** DLLvlImageCreateMultiple(unsigned int uiCount)
   {
      ...

      return lpNewImageDataRGBA8888;
   }
   ```

   or
2. Return the memory allocated in the output argument by passing the argument as a reference.

   ```
   void DLLvlImageCreateMultiple(unsigned int uiCount,
                                 unsigned char**& lpImageDataRGBA8888)
   {
      ...
   }
   ```

No matter which path you choose, you have to make sure that memory allocated in `process` is deallocated before the value of the pointer is changed.

```
void process()
{
   unsigned char** lpImageDataRGBA8888 = 0;
   unsigned int uiCount = 1; // frames
   unsigned int uiImageSize = 1024 * 1024 * 4; // width * height * byte per pixel

   lpImageDataRGBA8888 = new unsigned char* [uiCount];
   memset(lpImageDataRGBA8888, 0, uiCount * sizeof(unsigned char*));
   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < uiCount; i++)
   {
      lpImageDataRGBA8888[i] = new unsigned char[uiImageSize];
   }

   trap(lpImageDataRGBA8888, uiCount);

   DLLvlImageCreateMultiple(uiCount, lpImageDataRGBA8888);

   trap(lpImageDataRGBA8888, uiCount);
}
```

Otherwise, you will leak the memory allocated in `process`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it will be the most correct for the solution. but in the end, I just avoided using the code portion of the dynamic library that I used. and I could not change it.

Answer (score 0):

So basically the way the heap works is to allocate big blocks of memory as needed and give requested space to new objects. Typically PAGE_SIZE is 0x1000 bytes, which is the bare minimum block size the heap manager can allocate. Many structures may only use 0x40 bytes of that heap page for example, so it would be a massive waste of resources as well as causing other major issues to free the entire page allocated anytime something is removed from the heap. When you free something from the heap then it will be typically marked as such by the heap manager so other allocations can use that space. Depending on your OS there may be an option to zero memory when freeing, but you could also just do that yourself.

**Additional explanation from my comment after you included a small reproducible sample.**

> You are reallocating memory in `DLLvlImageCreateMultiple` with the expectation of `lpImageDataRGBA8888` being set to the new allocation. The original allocation from process gets freed but the second one is not. This means you have a memory leak of `(256 * 256 * 4 * 10240) = 2,684,354,560 bytes` if the loop manages to finish.

Comment: This is too general. I don't think this will help the OP figure out where the problem is in their code and how to resolve it.

Comment: Was it not a specific answer to his question of ``Why my heaps do not get cleared after they are deleted?`` As for his crash there's not enough information but I suspect he's making huge numbers of allocations, filling up many pages in the heap, exhausting memory. When those allocations are freed, the OS makes no guarantee the page it used will be freed so memory availability is still significantly lower than it should be. I could get into OS paging (which should prevent that problem, depends on OS and HW) but it seems outside the scope of this question.

Comment: I presented a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You are reallocating memory in ``DLLvlImageCreateMultiple`` with the expectation of ``lpImageDataRGBA8888`` being set to the new allocation. The original allocation from ``process`` gets freed but the second one is not. This means you have a memory leak of ``(256 * 256 * 4 * 10240) = 2,684,354,560`` bytes if the loop manages to finish.

Comment: yep. i too find it. it's memory leak in dll.